# Search bar filters in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: html, jquery, sql, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net

I would like to user firstly select the filters which is given in search bar dropdown like AREA or PRICE RANGE etc. I do not know how to put filter and also I want to display those search in on same page. I create this in ASP.NET Core MVC using ADO.NET for database using the SQL queries.

My view:

```
@model IEnumerable<eHouse.Models.RentModel>
<div class="navbar-left-section">
                <form>
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="search">
                            <input type="text" class="searchTerm" style="width: 700px; color:#000000; text-align: left;" placeholder="Search Houses">
                            <button type="submit" class="searchButton" >
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>

                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
</div>
```

Here is how I display the data:

```
<div class="property_information" >

           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
                <div class="home-info">
                    <span id="houseid">
                          
                    </span>
                  
                    <a href="#" class="home-images">
                        <img src="@item.pic1" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="home-data">
                        <div class="home-name">
                            <p>@item.tittle</p>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>@item.price</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="features">
                            <span>
                               @item.bedroom
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                 @item.bathroom
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                2
                            </span>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="desc">
                            @item.descrip
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-save">
                            <a href="#" class="phone_number" id="favorite" onclick="Fav(this)" data-id="@item.id" >
                                <i class="fas fa-heart" style=" color: white;"></i>
                            </a>
                        
                            <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
                            <a href="tel:+928754756478" class="phone_number" onclick="call()">
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="popupmsg" onclick="myFunctionmsg()">
                               <a href="#" class="phone_number open_message" onclick="msg()">
                               </a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="phone_number" onclick="del(this)" data-id="@item.id">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"  style=" color: white;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
    </div>
```

Here I want to just display the results of search.

My controller:

```
public IActionResult Rent(int PageNumber = 1)
{
    var data = rdb.GetDataHouse();
    var datas = rdb.GetDataHouse();
          
    ViewBag.Data = datas.ToList().Take(6);
          
    ViewBag.Totalpages = Math.Ceiling(data.Count()/6.0);

    data = data.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * 6).Take(6).ToList();

    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I  tried as below:
In View

```
@model SearchBarModel
<form asp-action="SearchBarTest">
    <a>Filter:</a>
    <input list="options" asp-for="FilterProperty" />
    <datalist id="options">
        <option value="Price"></option>
        <option value="Location"></option>
    </datalist>
    <br />
    <a>Range</a>
    <input list="range" asp-for="Range"/>
    <datalist id="range">
        
    </datalist>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    

    $("#FilterProperty").change(function () {
        var val = $("#FilterProperty").val()
        $("#range option").remove()
        if (val == "Price")
        {
            $("#range").append('<option value="10~20"></option>');
            $("#range").append('<option value="20~30"></option>');
        }
        if (val == "Location")
        {
            $("#range").append('<option value="China"></option>');
            $("#range").append('<option value="American"></option>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Model:

```
 public class SearchBarModel
    {
        public string FilterProperty { get; set; }
        public string Range { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SearchBarTest(string FilterProperty,string Range)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I do not want to make two input fields i just do with single input field

Comment: Hi,@Qasim Asghar,could you describe your requriement with more details?how you excepted the frontend and backend,the controller you've shown seems has no relationship with your view

Comment: i just shown a part of view not the whole view i agreed with the more then one filed but how i get data and display in view in the property information view

Comment: is it similar with what you've shown in this case?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609922/search-with-multiple-fields-in-asp-net-core-mvc